# (Beginner level) Problems with Python file

Tags: python

Before we start I'm a total noob to this stuff so bear over with me.

I downloaded a bot that should help me find codes on a webside. Link to bot: https://github.com/TAAPArthur/CrunchyrollGuestPassFinder

The code is writing in Python BTW. So I tried to run the bot in CMD and did everything it asked for but then a problem occurred.

Here is a picture:
[image]

It says there is no file named "/dev/null" and I tried to find it but there is nothing in the Firefox files. I don't know if it is something I need to download or what it is.

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: I think the bot isn't made to be run on Windows. "/dev/null" is a unix-based file system path, while you are using Windows, so the program can't find it

Comment: Without having looked deeper into this code, it looks like it is designed for a UNIX system which has `/dev/null` by default. On a Windows machine the corresponding file is called differently. However, if the code is designed for one OS type only, it might not be sufficient to just change this in case there are other OS-dependent features/structures used in the CrunchyrollGuestPassFinder.

Answer (score -1):

The service_log_path in the https://github.com/TAAPArthur/CrunchyrollGuestPassFinder/blob/master/crunchyroll-guest-pass-finder.py seems "dev/null"

This path is specific to UNIX and not windows.